# Bypassing iframe-like security with alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to display a web page which I modify by injecting code on its way to my user's browser. Like this:

- User visits a.mysite.com
- User sees the contents of google.com including styles etc, in a box within a.mysite.com
- Contents of google.com were modified at ma.mysite.com

Obviously if I didn't want the third part, an iframe would be a perfect solution. But the browser security model (appropriately) prevents me from modifying the contents.

Is there an easy way to have something like an iframe in rails but allow me to inject a javascript or similar? This is not for phishing, since the user will know I am in between them and the page - in fact that is a feature the user explicitly wants.

Comment: In other words, a server-side proxy that modifies the pages it serves.

Comment: @Slaks - precisely. Looking for one and the techniques required that would integrate nicely with a rails app.

Answer (score 0):

You could serve a proxy (so the actual browser request is to your site), which will rewrite parts of the page, to resolve relative urls in the page into urls pointing to your proxy too.

This may not work everywhere, because some code may need to check whether it is loaded from one place or another (I implemented such a security measure in a flash video player a while ago), and because you may end up proxying too many calls.

But this is the nearest way I know of